# Proving that $S(A):=(A+A^t)/2$ is self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, linear-transformations

I am having quite a hard time solving the following question:

[image: /qustion]

The standard inner space product is defined in the question.

All of the questions are correct, but I don't know how to prove it.

I know that for the first question, I need that a linear transformation be

$$
(Tu,v)=(u,Tv).
$$

Therefore, I try to solve the question with inner product, but every time I reach the following result:

[image: result]

The way I get to the result is with the rules of inner product, such as:

$$(u+v,w)=(u,w)+(v,w),$$
and using matrices algebra instead of linear transformation.

Unless I can prove that $A$ and $A^t$ are equal (and so are the $B$ and $B^t$), I can't see how I can prove the question.

Your help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: That is a strange question: It defines $S(A)$ but asks things about $A$. You cannot answer anything about $A$ without further information.

Comment: @daw I am very sorry, I have edited my question right now. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "standard inner-space product" which you mention is
$$
(A,B):=\mathrm{Tr}(A^tB),\quad A,B\in V.
$$
Using this definition, do you see how to prove that
$$
(A^t,B)=(A,B^t)?
$$

Comment: Is it the fact that the trace of the transpose is equal to the trace of the regular matrix?

Comment: I got it, thank you so much. Just make some calculation with the trace. thanks.

Comment: @Alan, yes indeed! Glad you were able to do the computations.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.